# Temporary S3 Bucket URL for serving Images

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Using "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.0@dev"

I am creating a image sharing website but do not want people to copy my URLs to another site to steal my content/bandwidth.

I was originally storing the objects as

```
return $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Body'   => $file,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
```

But I have removed 'public-read' so now the URL below no longer works

```
 https://mybucket-images.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/' . $key);
```

What do I need to do to create a temporary URL that can still be client side cached to access the object?

One thing I was thinking was to change the key once a week or month, but it would require me to update all objects with a cronjob. There must be a way to create a temporary access URL?

Comment: Who writes to the bucket - what are the bucket permissions?  If you are the only writer, not sure what the problem is - assuming the things you post are not confidential and of little value to a random reader.

Comment: My backend writes the images a user uploads to the bucket. All images are public but I want to prevent people copying my S3 URL to another site.

Comment: So you are trying to make it so that a client can access the URL if they got it from your site, but not if they read the URL from another site?

Comment: Kind of yeah, my website will generate a URL that can last 30 days or so, but then would expire and require my site to regenerate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your server to generate presigned url for the keys in the bucket.

```
//Creating a presigned request
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region'  => 'us-east-2',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
]);

$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => 'testKey'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

taken from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html

But you'd have to do this every time there's a request to your page. And the link will be valid everywhere. You just minimize the period of its validity.

**If your website is an API based and you retrieve the url via API**, this may be relevant to you:

- If your website has a login function, you can check for the auth logic prior giving the presigned url.
- If not, you can use Http Referrer (which can be spoofed). Or an api key (like in API Gateway)

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for, thanks! I will make the linked valid for 7 days I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
 // initiate connection to your S3 bucket
    $client = new S3Client(['credentials' => ['key' => 's3 key', 'secret' =>'s3 secrete'], 'region' => 's3 region', 'version' => 'latest']);

        $object = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => 's3 bucket',
            'Key' => 'images/image.png' // file
        ]);

        $presignedRequest = $client->createPresignedRequest($object, '+20 minutes');
        $presignedUrl = (string)$presignedRequest->getUri();
        if ($presignedUrl) {
            return $presignedUrl;//presigned URL
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to make your content readable ONLY via a URL posted on your website - versus having the same web client using the same url accessed from another site NOT work, I think you are likely to find that rather difficult.  Most of the ways that come to mind are fairly spoofable.

I would take a look at this and see if its good enough for you:

[Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)